# I get error in strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "2\r": invalid syntax prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I want to monitor hangfire dashboard(https://github.com/mfberkdemir/hangfireExporter) but the problem is prometheus is gibing me this error what this can be?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus scraper float parser expects metric lines to end with "\n" character, and NOT with "\r\n" NOR "\r".

Please verify that your metric data is exported in proper format.

This is described in https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/
in **Basic Info** -> **Encoding**.